# User input for SPARQL query in a python function

Tags: python, function, sparql

I am writing a function in python which calls a SPARQL endpoint of an API. I would like to modify the query (mesh:"+d+" meshv:treeNumber ?treeNum .) according to the user input. Below is my function.

```
def get_disease(d):
    query = '''
        PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
        PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
        PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
        PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
        PREFIX meshv: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#>
        PREFIX mesh: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/>
        PREFIX mesh2022: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2022/>
        

        SELECT DISTINCT ?descriptor ?label
        FROM <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh>

        WHERE {
        mesh:"+d+" meshv:treeNumber ?treeNum .
        ?childTreeNum meshv:parentTreeNumber+ ?treeNum .
        ?descriptor meshv:treeNumber ?childTreeNum .
        ?descriptor rdfs:label ?label .
        }

        ORDER BY ?label
        '''

    #set the url
    url = 'https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/sparql'
    #set the header
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/sparql-results+json'}
    #set the parameters
    params = {'query' : query, 'limit' : 1000, 'inference' : 'true', 'format' : 'JSON'}
    
    #send the request
    response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = params)
    jsonResponse = response.json()['results']
    
get_disease('D020521')
```

I looked the previous posts which shows that '"+d+"' concatenation of the input term ('D020521') should works in this case. However I am getting below error.

```
JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] Encountered " <STRING_LITERAL2> "\"+d+\" "" at line 16, column 14.
Was expecting one of:
    <IRIref> ...
    <PNAME_NS> ...
    <PNAME_LN> ...
    <VAR1> ...
    <VAR2> ...
    "a" ...
    "distinct" ...
    "multi" ...
    "shortest" ...
    "(" ...
    "!" ...
    "^" ...
    : 0
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what does `jsonResponse = response.json()` return? It seems that your response is not json

Comment: I get what I posted above. However, if i give the input in the query I get the output

Comment: please read again about Python string interpolation - what you currently do you open a multiline string in inside the string using double quotes. indeed that won't break the multiline string. either your do `'''text1''' + '''text2 '''` - or you use Python string interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @UninformedUser. The below changes in the script worked!

´´´
def get_disease(d):

```
query = '''
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
    PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
    PREFIX meshv: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#>
    PREFIX mesh: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/>
    PREFIX mesh2022: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2022/>

    SELECT DISTINCT ?descriptor ?label
    FROM <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh>

    WHERE {
    #mesh:D020521 meshv:treeNumber ?treeNum .
    mesh:%s meshv:treeNumber ?treeNum .
    ?childTreeNum meshv:parentTreeNumber+ ?treeNum .
    ?descriptor meshv:treeNumber ?childTreeNum .
    ?descriptor rdfs:label ?label .
    }

    ORDER BY ?label
    '''%(d)
#set the url
url = 'https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/sparql'
#set the header
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/sparql-results+json'}
#set the parameters
params = {'query' : query, 'limit' : 1000, 'inference' : 'true', 'format' : 'JSON'}

#send the request
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = params)
jsonResponse = response.json()['results']
print (jsonResponse)
```

get_disease('D020521')
´´´